# Prepare synatax error SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, sql, syntax, pdo

```
$tconn = new PDO('mysql:host='.WW_HST.';dbname='.WW_DB, WW_USR, WW_PS);
$res = $tconn->prepare('SELECT * FROM :tbl');
$res->execute(array(':tbl'=>"ugb"));
```

When I use this code to draw data from the 'ugb' table, I get the following error:

> 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ugb'' at line 1'

So it's correctly substituting `:tbl` for 'ugb' but whether I do a bind or just execute with an array, I always get an error. It works fine if I just do `SELECT * FROM ugb` though.

How can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 2):

PDO does not allow you to set variables in FROM.

You only could add table name in query string.

I usually do by this way:

```
$allowedTables = array('first', 'second', 'third');
if(in_array($tblName, $allowedTables)) {
  $$res = $tconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tblName");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that PDO will allow you to bind a parameter to the FROM statement. You could try manualy escaping the table name parameter and after that adding it to the query like this:

```
$table = "ugb";
$tconn = new PDO('mysql:host='.WW_HST.';dbname='.WW_DB, WW_USR, WW_PS);
$res = $tconn->prepare('SELECT * FROM '. $tconn->quote($table));
$res->execute();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is a scary one. Please read comments on the manual page for the function you suggested.

Comment: Yes you'r right, but it may serve some purpose in this case.